Interval Placement
Given two intervals A and B, decide if A can be translated and placed into B. You can assume both given interval has some measure(or say length).
aka. Exist d, for all x in A, x+d is in B.
Both extreme points are positive integers but can be either open or close(given in input, flexible form). Moved distance needn't be integer, though.
Test cases:
[1,2], [1,3] => true
[1,2], (1,3) => true  (d can't be integer but it's fine)
[1,2], [8,9] => true
[8,9), [1,2) => true
(1,9), (1,9) => true
[1,4], [3,5] => false
(8,9], [1,2) => false (rotating is not allowed)
(7,9), [1,2] => false

Now some simple challenges onto main, CMC isn't quite active

@emanresuA Both extreme points are positive integers.  to avoid float error and simple some languages

In that case, can "flexible input" include e.g. taking the range(1, 4] as the pair [1.1, 4] or similar?

@emanresuA iff meta allows strong a bool there

With the flexible input, could we take an additional flag indicating it's an exclusive/inclusive range? So instead of [n or n] would be [n,0] and instead of (n or n) would be [n,1] be ok (e.g. (8,9], [1,2) would be input as [[8,1],[9,0]], [[1,0],[2,1]])?

@KevinCruijssen Expected.

Python 3 + SymPy, 80 bytes
lambda a,b:a.measure<b.measure+a.xreplace({a.inf:b.inf,a.sup:b.sup}).issubset(b)

Try it online!
Input two sympy.set.set.Interval, output bool.

Python 3, 41 bytes
lambda s,e,l,r,S,E,L,R:1>S-s-E+e<=l-L|r-R

Try it online!
Input 8 parameters as (start_a: int, end_a: int, left_open_a: bool, right_open_a: bool, start_b: int, end_b: int, left_open_b: bool, right_open_b: bool)...
-3 bytes by Albert.Lang

41 bytes

Do you need the 1> in your second solution?

@Shaggy yes, and one also needs to fix the order of the two last differences which I got wrong (sorry tsh) Fixed (I hope) version

05AB1E, 17 bytes
ÆD`‹sËIËI`ßs_~~*~

Two separated inputs: the first is a pair of reversed pairs of integers. And the second is a pair of pairs of bits (in either order), where 1 indicates inclusive and 0 indicates exclusive (e.g. (8,9], [1,2) would have inputs [[9,8],[2,1]] and ["01","10"]/["10","01"]).
Try it online or verify all test cases.
Inspired by @Neil's Retina answer, so make sure to upvote that answer as well!
Explanation:
In pseudo-code:

Get the amount of items in both ranges if we would parse it as a regular [a,b)-range (inclusive start, exclusive end).
The result is now truthy if any of these four options is truthy:

The amount of items of the second range is larger than the first
OR the amount of items are the same, and the inclusiveness/exclusiveness of both ranges are matching (e.g. (a,b),(c,d) / (a,b],(c,d] / [a,b),[c,d) / [a,b],[c,d])
OR the amount of items are the same, and the second range is inclusive on both ends (e.g. (a,b),[c,d] / (a,b],[c,d] / [a,b),[c,d] / [a,b],[c,d])
OR the amount of items are the same, and the first range is exclusive on both ends (e.g. (a,b),(c,d) / (a,b),(c,d] / (a,b),[c,d) / (a,b),[c,d])



Æ          # Reduce the inner pairs of the first (implicit) input by subtracting
           #  e.g. [[9,8],[2,1]] → [1,1]
 D`‹       # Option 1:
 D         #  Duplicate it
  `        #  Pop and push both values separated to the stack
           #   → 1,1
   ‹       #  Check if the second is larger than the first
           #   → 0 (falsey)
 s         # Swap so the duplicated pair is at the top again
  Ë        # Check if both integers in this pair are the same
           #  → 1 (truthy)
   IË      # Option 2:
   I       #  Push the second input-pair of bit-strings
    Ë      #  Check if both are the same
           #   e.g. ["01","10"] → 0 (falsey)
   I`ß     # Option 3:
   I       #  Push the second input-pair of bit-strings again
    `      #  Pop and push both separated to the stack
           #   → "01","10"
     ß     #  Pop the second one, and push its minimum
           #  (1 if it was 11; 0 if it was 00/01/10)
           #   "10" → 0 (falsey)
    s_     # Option 4:
    s      #  Swap so the first one is at the top now
     _     #  Pop and check whether it is 0
           #  (1 if it was 00; 0 if it was 01/10/11)
           #   "01" → 0 (falsey)
      ~~*~ # Or,Or,And,Or to combine all checks:
      ~~   #  Options 2, 3, OR 4
           #   0,0,0 → 0 (falsey)
        *  #  AND both items were the same
           #   1,0 → 0 (falsey)
         ~ #  Or option 1
           #   0,0 → 0 (falsey)
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)


I feel as if this gives the wrong answer for [[[8,1],[9,0]],[[1,0],[3,1]]].

@Neil Thanks for noticing. I completely revised my answer and now that test case is correct as well.

Retina 0.8.2, 50 bytes
\d+
$*
(1+),\1

^(.)(1+)(.),(.1\2|(\1|\[)\2(\3|]))

Try it online! Link includes test cases. Explanation:
\d+
$*

Convert to unary.
(1+),\1
 

Get just the lengths of each range.
^(.)(1+)(.),(.1\2|(\1|\[)\2(\3|]))

Match if the second range is longer than the first, or if it's at least as closed as the first.

Your explanation, particularly "Get just the lengths of each range.", isn't entirely accurate. Because the [1,2] becomes [1,11] after converting to unary, but then [1] in your second step (even though the range [1,2] is two items instead of 1).

@KevinCruijssen The range [1, 2] isn't two items, it's all real numbers from 1 up to and including 2. All ranges over the same interval have the same length whether they're closed or open, but obviously only closed ranges contain the zero-width end points.

Japt, 16 bytes
+2 bytes because I think I misinterpreted the flexibility of the input.
cVon)r- §WínX r|

Takes input as 4 arrays, with B being the first (U), A the second (V), and the 3rd (W) & 4th (X) representing whether each end of B & A, respectively, is inclusive (1) or exclusive (0).
Try it
cVon)r- §WínX r|     :Implicit input of arrays U, V, W & X
c                    :Concatenate to U
 Vo                  :  Modify last element of V
   n                 :    Negate
    )                :End concat
     r-              :Reduce by subtraction
        §            :Less than or equal to
         Wí X        :  Interleave W & X
           n         :  Reducing each pair by inverse subtraction
              r|     :  Reduce by bitwise OR


Charcoal, 24 bytes
≔Ｅη⁻ι§θκυ‹⊖⊙()№υι⁻§υ²§υ¹

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a pair of lists [char_lower, int_lower, int_upper, char_upper]. Explanation:
≔Ｅη⁻ι§θκυ

Pairwise subtract the two inputs. The ints just subtract normally of course, while the chars turn into empty strings if they match.
‹⊖⊙()№υι⁻§υ²§υ¹

Check that the resulting range length is non-negative unless there was an open range matched with a closed range in which case the range length needs to be positive.
50 bytes for a more parsed version:
ＦＥ²Ｓ⊞υ⟦§ι⁰↨Ｉ⪪✂ι¹±¹¦¹,±¹§ι±¹⟧≔Ｅ⊟υ⁻ι§⌈υκυ‹⊖⊙()№υι§υ¹

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as two newline-separated range strings. Explanation:
ＦＥ²Ｓ⊞υ⟦§ι⁰↨Ｉ⪪✂ι¹±¹¦¹,±¹§ι±¹⟧

Input and parse the two strings, calculating the length of the range.
≔Ｅ⊟υ⁻ι§⌈υκυ

Pairwise subtract the two inputs.
‹⊖⊙()№υι§υ¹

Check that the resulting range length is non-negative unless there was an open range matched with a closed range in which case the range length needs to be positive.

R, 52 51 50 bytes
-2 by @pajonk:

Simplified logic: (¬A)&B = ¬(A|B)

Renamed diff to ?


\(x,i,`?`=diff,d=?x)d[2]>d[1]|!any(d[2]-d[1],0>?i)

Attempt This Online!
Input:

x is a 2x2 matrix with one column for each interval
i is a 2x2 logical matrix for whether the corresponding bound in x is closed

R's operator precedence just happens to be such that I didn't need any extra parentheses (with weird things like - is before !). Also handy is that diff(t(x))[2]-diff(t(x))[1] == diff(x)[2]-diff(x)[1] for a 2x2 matrix.

-1 byte

Another -1 by renaming diff to ? (or any unary operator actually).

Python3, 78 bytes
lambda a,A,b,B,c,C,d,D:(A==B and C==D)+(A==C or B==D)and(b-a,-A-B)<=(d-c,-C-D)

Try it online!

Uiua, 14 12 bytes
+×⊓×⊃≍>⊓∩=∩-

Pad
Uses input format al bl ar br a1 b1 a2 b2, where a1 and a2 are the endpoints of a and  al and ar are 0 for a closed intervals, and 1 for an open intervals e.g. [2,3) [4,5) gives 0 0 1 1 2 3 4 5 (if this doesn't fall under "flexible", let me know).
Explanation
\$a\$ fits into \$b\$ iff \$|a|<|b|\$ or \$|a|=|b|\$ and the endpoints are the same openness, which is implemented as so:
+×⊓×⊃≍>⊓∩=∩-   # calculate interval fit
       ⊓  ∩-   # subtract each interval
       ⊓∩=     # for each side (left and right), compare openness
+              # intervals fit if either...
 ×             # both:
  ⊓×           # both sides have same openness
  ⊓ ⊃≍         # and intervals are the same size
  ⊓ ⊃ >        # ...or |b| > |a|

